# Android emulator display screen corruption

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

The emulator is working fine, and I can interact with it normally, but the bars at the top and bottom are extremely smeared and it's got these weird diagonal lines in the middle.

This is a screenshot of a Nexus 4, API 28. The screen corruption does not always appear - for instance, Nexus 5 API 27 works perfectly.

What causes this, and how can I fix it?

[image: screenshot]